# How to get around eclipse toolbar rationing?

Tags: eclipse

By default, eclipse only puts items in the toolbar I never use.  With customize perspective, I am able to take these out, but I am not allowed to put in commands I actually use regularly, such as Search File, and a a bunch of SVN commands, ... and now when I select 'previous edit' to put in the toolbar it doesnt show up.  Is there a way to fix this?

ps rant: The "search" tool button dropdown is the same number of clicks as the search menu!!!  This defeats the whole point of a one click toolbar!!!!!

Edit
While we'are at it, removing everything in the right click menu of the file navigator between "Refresh" and "Properties" would be nice too.

Comment: I'd learn how to set up and use keyboard shortcuts.  Way better in the long run anyway :-). E.g. search is CTRL-H.  Also search is one-click if you just click the button and not the arrow to the side; but it might send you to the wrong tab.

Comment: What steps did you use to "select 'previous edit' to put in the toolbar"?

Comment: +1 Would love to know how to put a search files button there.

Comment: @Mark Peter: Right Click toolbar > Customize perspective > Toolbar Visibility, its still checked under Navigate, but I don't see it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the best you're going to get is Window -- Customize Perspective and then select/deselect items in "Command Groups Availability".

It's up to plugin authors to "contribute" commands, so if they don't do so in their plugin.xml files, then those commands will not show up in these lists.

Comment: Is it possible/advisable to edit this xml to make the commands I want toolbarable?

Comment: it's possible, but not advised. You're getting into "here be dragons" territory, because you'll have to learn all about action and commands, contributions, etc, and you'd be getting into a cycle of edit / restart / break / edit restart because you really have no way to test your changes otherwise. It'll be a time sink, and they'll get overwritten when the plugin is updated. I'd advise contacting the plugin authors first. If I were you, I'd spend my time learning the keybindings for the actions instead of using the toolbar